# Replace conditional values with NA without declassing variables in dplyr

Tags: r

I need to replace certain values within a factor with NA using tidyverse packages.

Here's some toy data

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = factor(letters[1:5]),
             v2 = 1:5)

glimpse(df)

# Rows: 5
# Columns: 2
# $ v1 <fct> a, b, c, d, e
# $ v2 <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Now, say we want to replace `b` or `d` with NA. We can use `ifelse()`

```
df %>%
  mutate(v1 = ifelse(v1 %in% c("b", "d"), NA, v1)) %>%
    glimpse

# Rows: 5
# Columns: 2
# $ v1 <int> 1, NA, 3, NA, 5
# $ v2 <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

And it *sort of* works, but it also declasses the factor, turning it into a numeric, which is not what we want

Is there a way to get what I want without declassing the variable? I tried na_if but that doesn't work with conditionals (i.e. you can only replace single values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `recode_factor` from the `dplyr` package which has technically been superseded, but there is no direct replacement yet. You pass it name-replacement pairs:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  mutate(v1 = recode_factor(v1, d = NA_character_))
```

**Update**

For multiple values use the splice `!!!` operator to inject your list:

```r
x <- c("b", "d")
nm <- setNames(rep(NA_character_, length(x)), x)

df |> 
  mutate(v1 = recode_factor(v1, !!! nm))
```

---

Or in base R you can set the level to `NA` in place:

```r
levels(df$v1)[levels(df$v1) == "d"] <- NA
```

Comment: thank you @LMc. The tidyverse solution works but was not quite what I want as it seems to only be for a single case. Is there any way to get a proper conditional? I realise I was not clear and have re-framed the example question differently

Comment: @llewmills you still do not need a conditional. See my update.

Comment: Thank you so much @LMc. Can you explain what `setNames()` does?

Comment: It just creates name value pairs that when unpacked by `!!!`, the names become the lefthand side and the values the righthand side (eg `d = NA_character_`)

Comment: You can use any named object. I used a named vector created with `setNames` but you could also use a named list. Wrap the expression in `rlang::qq_show` and check out the output.

Comment: If you want to pipe the base version into `mutate` you can do something like: `df %>% mutate(v1 = {levels(v1)[levels(v1) %in% c("b","d")] <- NA; v1})`